# Pip install of a specific git commit failing via Ansible Playbook

Tags: git, pip, ansible

In this example, Django-cities fails.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   - name: Install Django
     pip: name=Django
   - name: Install Userena
     pip: name=django-userena
   - name: Install Django Messages
     pip: name=https://github.com/arneb/django-messages/archive/master.zip
   - name: Install Django Cities
     pip: name=git+https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities.git@d0163f393e7557914b3f2c6882e740537ca63fd6
```

error:

```
TASK [Install Django Cities] ***************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/pip2 install -e git+https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities.git@d0163f393e7557914b3f2c6882e740537ca63fd6", 
"failed": true, "msg": "\n:stderr: --editable=git+https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities.git@d0163f393e7557914b3f2c6882e740537ca63fd6 is not the right format; it must have #egg=Package\nYou are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.\nYou should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.\n"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/root/cannablr/ansible/playbooks/installdjango.retry
```

Is install of a git commit via pip not allowed in Ansible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get the same error if you run this on the commandline:

```
$ pip install -e git+https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities.git@d0163f393e7557914b3f2c6882e740537ca63fd6
--editable=git+https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities.git@d0163f393e7557914b3f2c6882e740537ca63fd6 is not the right format; it must have #egg=Package
```

You can add an `#egg=packagename` to it and it'll work:

```
$ pip install -e git+https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities.git@d0163f393e7557914b3f2c6882e740537ca63fd6#egg=django-cities
Obtaining django-cities from git+https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities.git@d0163f393e7557914b3f2c6882e740537ca63fd6#egg=django-cities
  Cloning https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities.git (to d0163f393e7557914b3f2c6882e740537ca63fd6) to src/django-cities
```

So just add `#egg=django-cities` to the URL in Ansible and you'll be good.

Note I'd recommend quoting your `git+https://....#egg=xyz` yaml. There are a lot of magic characters in there.